# Query Datetime field in SPList

Tags: sharepoint, caml, splist

Can u tell me how to compare the date as well as time stored in a SPList as a DateTime field with the current system time using a CAML query?

Answer (score 5):

To compare with todays date:

```
<Where>
  <Lt>
    <FieldRef Name='Created'/>
    <Value type='DateTime'><Today /></Value>
  </Lt>
</Where>
```

To compare todays date AND time

```
<Where>
  <Lt>
    <FieldRef Name='Created'/>
    <Value type='DateTime' IncludeDateTime='TRUE'><Today /></Value>
  </Lt>
</Where>
```

To compare yesterdays date

```
<Where>
  <Lt>
    <FieldRef Name='Created'/>
    <Value type='DateTime'><Today Offset='-1' /></Value>
  </Lt>
</Where>
```

Answer (score 2):

To compare yesterday's date should be "OffsetDays"

```
<Where>
  <Lt>
    <FieldRef Name='Created'/>
    <Value type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-1' /></Value>
  </Lt>
</Where>
```